# Amazon web service signature issue in postman

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, retrofit

Reponse Like this.
**The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.**

Comment: Please post a code snippet, a description of the problem, the AWS SDK and the version you are using?